# Sonar blocker for managed "ame" + flex project

Tags: actionscript-3, events, apache-flex, sonarqube

I'm trying to fix bocker given by sonar for a Flex+ actionScript3 web application.

I was faced to this unresolvable blocker:

> The managed event "ame" is either misspelled or is missing a companion
>   Event metadata tag

My code is as follows:

```
    [Bindable]  
    [ManagedEvents(names="message")]
    public class ClassName extends EventDispatcher
    {
      .........
     }
```

I tried to fix this issue as follows:

```
    [Bindable]
    [Event(name="message",type="package.ClassEvent")]
    [ManagedEvents(names="message")]
    public class ClassName extends EventDispatcher
    {
      ....    
     }
```

Where in package.ClassEvent is the declared event "message"

```
[Command(selector="message")]
public function message(evt:NameEvent):AsyncToken
{           
    .....
}
```

PS: Sonar suggest as solution :

> The "ManagedEvents" metadata tag allows you to flag an event as being
>   managed. By definition this "ManageEvents" metadata tag should be used
>   in pair with an "Event" metadata tag.
>
> Noncompliant Code Example
>
> [Event(name="message", type="my.package.MyEvemt")]
>   [ManagedEvents("mes")]       //This "mes" event is not defined with
>   the "Event" metadata tag public class MyClass {...} 
>   Compliant Solution
>   [Event(name="message", type="my.package.MyEvemt")]
>   [ManagedEvents("message")] public class MyClass {...}

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Sonar.
This ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARFLEX-88 should fix your problem. While it's not fixed you can mark issue as false positive.

Comment: i fixed it by not mention the attribute names in the managedEvents :